# Dataframe PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge duplicate rows in a particular column and rearranging the data. For instance, I have the following dataframe:

```
 FROM    CONT    ID1    ID2    ID3    ID4    ID5    ID6    ID7
 63309    89     101.3  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 63309    89     NA     102.3  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 63309    89     NA     NA     NA     104    NA     NA     NA
 63309    90     NA     NA     103    105.0  NA     NA     NA
 63309    89     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     107.1  NA
 63310    92     NA     105.1  105.3  789.1  104    NA     NA
 63310    92     109    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 63311    94     104    109    890    NA     NA     NA     107
 63309    89     NA     NA     NA     NA     109    NA     111
```

I want my result in the following format:

```
 FROM    CONT    ID1    ID2    ID3    ID4    ID5    ID6    ID7
 63309    89     101.3  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
          89     NA     102.3  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
          89     NA     NA     NA     104    NA     NA     NA
          90     NA     NA     103    105.0  NA     NA     NA
          89     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     107.1  NA
          89     NA     NA     NA     NA     109    NA     111

 63310    92     NA     105.1  105.3  789.1  104    NA     NA
          92     109    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA

 63311    94     104    109    890    NA     NA     NA     107
```

I know I can use df.sort() to arrange it in ascending order. What I'm looking for particular is the formatting of the 'FROM' column and adding an empty space once there is a transition from one unique 'FROM' row to the next unique 'FROM' row.

Comment: Please have the title of the question carry more information than it does at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df.set_index(['FROM', 'CONT']).sort_index()

              ID1    ID2    ID3    ID4  ID5    ID6  ID7
FROM  CONT                                             
63309 89    101.3    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
      89      NaN  102.3    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
      89      NaN    NaN    NaN  104.0  NaN    NaN  NaN
      89      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN  107.1  NaN
      89      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  109    NaN  111
      90      NaN    NaN  103.0  105.0  NaN    NaN  NaN
63310 92      NaN  105.1  105.3  789.1  104    NaN  NaN
      92    109.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
63311 94    104.0  109.0  890.0    NaN  NaN    NaN  107
```

You don't want spacer rows in your dataframe.  That is a formatting issue.